# pyPdf output files are the same size regardless of page count

Tags: python, pdf, bookmarks, pypdf

I'm trying to use pyPdf to extract a few pages from a large pdf to a separate file. Whenever I do, the resulting filesize is nearly identical to the source file. I think it has something to do with the bookmarks inside the files, because it the output file size is very small if the page doesn't contain any links. I can't figure out how to exclude the bookmarks from the output file.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter as writer, PdfFileReader as reader
w = writer()
r = reader(open('9.pdf'))

for p in xrange(5):
    w.addPage(r.getPage(p))
with open('out.pdf', 'wb') as stream:
    w.write(stream)

w._objects
# prints:

{'/Kids': [IndirectObject(4, 0), IndirectObject(5, 0), IndirectObject(6, 0), IndirectObject(7, 0), IndirectObject(8, 0)], '/Type': '/Pages', '/Count': 5}
{'/Producer': u'Python PDF Library - http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/'}
{'/Type': '/Catalog', '/Pages': IndirectObject(1, 0)}
{'/Parent': IndirectObject(1, 0), '/Rotate': 0, '/Contents': IndirectObject(4307, 0), '/Resources': {'/ColorSpace': {'/CS1': IndirectObject(4309, 0), '/CS0': IndirectObject(4305, 0)}, '/XObject': {'/Im0': IndirectObject(4312, 0)}, '/ExtGState': {'/GS2': IndirectObject(4324, 0), '/GS1': IndirectObject(4323, 0), '/GS0': IndirectObject(4306, 0)}, '/Font': {'/T1_2': IndirectObject(4308, 0), '/T1_0': IndirectObject(4303, 0), '/T1_1': IndirectObject(4304, 0)}, '/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text', '/ImageB']}, '/CropBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/BCLPrivAnnots': {'/BCLC_BCL_Jade': []}, '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/Annots': IndirectObject(4301, 0), '/Type': '/Page'}
{'/Parent': IndirectObject(1, 0), '/Contents': IndirectObject(2, 0), '/Resources': {'/ColorSpace': {'/CS1': IndirectObject(4309, 0), '/CS0': IndirectObject(4305, 0)}, '/ExtGState': {'/GS2': IndirectObject(3417, 0), '/GS1': IndirectObject(3412, 0), '/GS0': IndirectObject(4306, 0)}, '/Font': {'/T1_2': IndirectObject(3413, 0), '/T1_0': IndirectObject(3415, 0), '/T1_1': IndirectObject(3416, 0)}, '/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text']}, '/Rotate': 0, '/CropBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/BCLPrivAnnots': {'/BCLC_BCL_Jade': []}, '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/Thumb': IndirectObject(3920, 0), '/Type': '/Page'}
{'/Parent': IndirectObject(1, 0), '/Contents': IndirectObject(4, 0), '/Resources': {'/ColorSpace': {'/CS0': IndirectObject(4305, 0)}, '/ExtGState': {'/GS0': IndirectObject(4306, 0)}, '/Font': {'/T1_2': IndirectObject(3425, 0), '/T1_3': IndirectObject(3428, 0), '/T1_0': IndirectObject(3426, 0), '/T1_1': IndirectObject(3427, 0)}, '/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text']}, '/Rotate': 0, '/CropBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/BCLPrivAnnots': {'/BCLC_BCL_Jade': []}, '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/Thumb': IndirectObject(3921, 0), '/Type': '/Page'}
{'/Parent': IndirectObject(1, 0), '/Contents': IndirectObject(6, 0), '/Resources': {}, '/Rotate': 0, '/CropBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/BCLPrivAnnots': {'/BCLC_BCL_Jade': []}, '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/Thumb': IndirectObject(3922, 0), '/Type': '/Page'}
{'/Parent': IndirectObject(1, 0), '/Contents': IndirectObject(9, 0), '/Resources': IndirectObject(8, 0), '/Rotate': 0, '/CropBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/BCLPrivAnnots': {'/BCLC_BCL_Jade': []}, '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/Thumb': IndirectObject(3923, 0), '/Type': '/Page'}
```

Comment: Don't forget that pyPdf doesn't compress the ouput, while the input you use is probably compressed.

Answer (score -2):

When using PyPdf, the output file is striped of almost all formatting.

specifically, replace:

```
with open('out.pdf', 'wb') as stream:
    w.write(stream)
```

for:

```
stream = file('out.pdf', 'wb')
w.write(stream)
stream.close()
```

then look at the end result.

It is also good practice to write :

```
fin = open('9.pdf')
r = reader(fin)
fin.close()
```

and not:

```
r = reader(open('9.pdf'))
```

Comment: How is that any better than using 'with', which always closes the file, even when an exception is thrown?

Comment: I had a script that corrupted a pdf file using `with`. Better be on the safe side.

Comment: But `with` _is_ the safe side.

Comment: ... I don't see how this applies.. I think I'll stick with 'with'