# How can I split a PDF file by its pages into PDF files of a smaller size with PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pdf, split, pypdf

I wrote simple python code that gets PDF, goes over its pages using PyPDF2 and saves each page as new PDF file.
see page save function here:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter


def save_pdf_page(file_name, page_index):
    reader = PdfReader(file_name)
    writer = PdfWriter()
    writer.add_page(reader.pages[page_index])
    writer.remove_links()
    with open(f"output_page{page_index}.pdf", "wb") as fh:
        writer.write(fh)
```

Surprisingly each page is about the same size as the original PDF file.
using removeLinks (taken from [here](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/449)) didn't reduce page size

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614014/pypdf4-exported-pdf-file-size-too-big), saying it may be caused because PyPDF output files are uncompressed.

Is there a way using PyPDF or any other python lib to make each page relatively small as expected?

Comment: You are right. I realized I didn't ask the right question. should have asked why split and merge back results much bigger file then original one

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this issue: https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/449

Essentially the are two problems:

1. Every page might need a resource which is shared, eg font information
2. PyPDF2 might not realize if some pages don't need it

Remove links might help. Additionally, you might want to [follow the docs to reduce file size](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/file-size.html):

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("test.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()
for page_num in [2, 3]:
    page = reader.pages[page_num]

    # This is CPU intensive! It ZIPs the contents of the page
    page.compress_content_streams()

    writer.add_page(page)


with open("seperate.pdf", "wb") as fh:
    writer.remove_links()
    writer.write(fh)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, remove_links didn't reduce files size in my case.

I realized my main problem is the size of merged PDF file back from splited pages. seems like PyPDF2 doesn't optimize well when merging PDF files into one